# SQL Statement - How to write a WHERE clause with wildcard

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wildcard

I have a C# application that includes a SQL query that includes this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
    A.Location = @Location
    AND Widgets.Branch = @Branch
```

The requirements have changed such that users can ask to see ALL branches. I know I can write an if statement to see if I have a branch parameter that's been passed in... and then have a different select statement that omits the AND clause for the branch altogether.

But I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this? Could I pass in some sort of a wildcard?

I tried '*' or '%' but that doesn't seem to be the right syntax.  I know % is used with the LIKE...

Any suggestions / tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

So I'm trying to figure out how to use the

```
WHERE 
    A.Location = @Location
    AND (@Branch IS NULL OR Widgets.Branch = @Branch)
```

approach.

My code in part looks like this:

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
      activityByUserType = conn.Query<ActivityDetailsByUserTypes>(
      @"
                SELECT 
                    ReportRefreshDate,
                    other columns...
                FROM 
                    (SELECT
                         columns
                     FROM table1 A
                     INNER JOIN Widgets ON LOWER(fieldAA) = LOWER(A.fieldAA)
                     WHERE 
                         A.Location = @Location
                         AND Widgets.Branch = @Branch) DetailedResults
                 GROUP BY ReportRefreshDate;
                ",
                new { Branch=branchId, Location = LocationId, RefreshDate = dateRange}).ToList();
        }
        return activityByUserType;
```

As you can see, I'm creating a new query object ... and passing a list of parameters to it at the end of the code block.

I changed the logic to add this if statement before the USING()

```
if (branchId.Equals("allbranches")) 
{
   branchId = null;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to really work.

Comment: *I know I can write an if statement .. and then have a different [where] statement that omits the AND clause for the branch altogether* - yes, you should

Comment: A search for tricks to avoid writing code (i.e., "simpler way") can lead to less efficient code. I leave you with Erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) which discusses this in the context of stored procedures - but the same considerations apply in your application code.

Comment: @CaiusJard can you explain why that approach is better?  That'd be helpful.

Comment: SMor's posted a link to a great deep-dive on it - it was the one I had in mind, but couldn't find..

Comment: @SMor if you post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: `LOWER(fieldAA) = LOWER(A.fieldAA)` have you considered just using a case-insensitive collation?

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the parameter is null in the `WHERE` clause:

```
    WHERE 
        A.Location = @Location
    AND
        (@Branch IS NULL OR Widgets.Branch = @Branch)
```

This won't filter the branch when `@Branch` parameter is null.

Comment: Or, [don't](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic)

Comment: @haldo, can you please check out EDIT 1 in my post?  Trying to figure out how to apply your approach to my code.

Comment: @dot you could try `(@Branch = 'allBranches' OR Widgets.Branch = @Branch)` instead?

Comment: @dot looks like you're using Dapper? Maybe you need to help the compiler infer the type when `branchId` is null: `new { Branch=(string)branchId, ...` and use with the new piece of code you added

Comment: @haldo in the end, I guess I'm going to use the long approach that I originally had on the brain just incase there are performance hits.  But, I'm upvoting your answer too cuz I that's the kind of approach I was wondering about and at least now I know it can be done!

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly check for an asterisk in the query itself:

```
@Branch IN ('*', Widgets.Branch)
```

This way, if you pass `@Branch=*`, the column is ignored, and otherwise it's compared to the value of the column.

Comment: Or, [don't](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic)